# give fetched data value to the xpath field in selenium

Tags: eclipse, selenium, xpath

```
File src = new File("F:\\Screenshots\\Book1.xlsx");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
String data0 = sheet1.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

//System.out.println("Data from Excel is "+data0);

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


driver.navigate().to("https://maps.mapmyindia.com/");

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='auto']"))
```

I want to give the value of data0 to that xpath field, please suggest me how should i do it. In this manner i will able to fetch data from excel sheet.

Comment: yes you are right, thank you

Comment: Is you question solved?